# Access Coinbase Create Account API using curl without OAuth2

Tags: coinbase-api, blockchain.info-api

I am using Coinbase Wallet Endpoints of Coinbase API in my application and trying to hit create_account API https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#create-account using curl without OAuth2. According to Coinbase documentation, curl command would be like:

```
    curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts \
    -X POST
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer 
    abd90df5f27a7b170cd775abf89d632b350b7c1c9d53e08b340cd9832ce52c2c' 
    -d '{"name": "New wallet"}'
```

I am unable to figure out what will be the value of access token and how I will get it without using OAuth2 request.

Please guide me that "How I will get Bearer access token without using OAuth2?".